# Right way to forcibly convert Maybe a to a in Elm, failing clearly for Nothings

Tags: elm, option-type

Okay, what I really wanted to do is, I have an Array and I want to  choose a random element from it. The obvious thing to do is get an integer from a random number generator between 0 and the length minus 1, which I have working already, and then applying [Array.get](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.1.1/Array#get), but that returns a `Maybe a`. (It appears there's also a [package function that does the same thing](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/Elm-Random-Sampling/2.0.1/Random-Array#sample).) Coming from Haskell, I get the type significance that it's protecting me from the case where my index was out of range, but I have control over the index and don't expect that to happen, so I'd just like to **assume I got a `Just` something and somewhat forcibly convert to `a`.** In Haskell this would be `fromJust` or, if I was feeling verbose, `fromMaybe (error "some message")`. **How should I do this in Elm?**

I found [a discussion on the mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.elm.general/4377) that seems to be discussing this, but it's been a while and I don't see the function I want in the standard library where the discussion suggests it would be.

Here are some pretty unsatisfying potential solutions I found so far:

- Just use [withDefault](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.1.1/Maybe#withDefault). I do have a default value of `a` available, but I don't like this as it gives the completely wrong meaning to my code and will probably make debugging harder down the road.
- Do some fiddling with ports to interface with Javascript and get an exception thrown there if it's Nothing. I haven't carefully investigated how this works yet, but apparently it's possible. But this just seems to mix up too many dependencies for what would otherwise be simple pure Elm.

Comment: "I have control over the index and don't expect [index out of range] to happen" -> What if the array is empty?

Comment: I updated my [nonempty list library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/elm-nonempty-list/1.7.0/List-Nonempty) with a `sample` function.

Comment: The two arrays I was considering when asking this question were both initialized to arrays with a fixed number of elements. They are never empty (modulo programmer error).

Answer (score 8):

(answering my own question)

I found two more-satisfying solutions:

- Roll my own partially defined function, which was [referenced elsewhere in the linked discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.elm.general/5765/focus=5769). But the code kind of feels incomplete this way (I'd hope the compiler would warn me about incomplete pattern matches some day) and the error message is still unclear.
- Pattern-match and use [Debug.crash](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.1.1/Debug#crash) if it's a Nothing. This appears similar to Haskell's `error` and is the solution I'm leaning towards right now.

  ```
  import Debug

  fromJust : Maybe a -> a
  fromJust x = case x of
      Just y -> y
      Nothing -> Debug.crash "error: fromJust Nothing"
  ```

  (Still, the module name and description also make me hesitate because it doesn't seem like the "right" method intended for my purposes; I want to indicate true programmer error instead of mere debugging.)

Comment: I think `Debug.crash` is the right approach. You may want to give a better message than "oh no!". You can always start a new thread on the mailing list about changing the name of `Debug.crash`.

Comment: In 0.16, the compiler will not allow incomplete pattern matching like `(\(Just x) -> x)`. `Debug.crash` is the way to go.

Comment: I think `Debug.crash` is a great name.  It is basically saying to only use this during debugging and don't put it in production.

Comment: That is exactly what the name suggests to me as well, but if so, how am I supposed to define `fromJust` in production?

Comment: Honestly, neither of these is the intended use of `Maybe` or `Option` and there are other ways around this. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41656722/2895548.

Comment: Since Elm 0.19, `Debug.crash` is no more and you'll have to find another way to deal with this.

Answer (score 5):

## Solution

The existence or use of a `fromJust` or equivalent function is actually code smell and tells you that the API has not been designed correctly. The problem is that you're attempting to make a decision on what to do before you have the information to do it. You can think of this in two cases:

1. If you know what you're supposed to do with `Nothing`, then the solution is simple: use `withDefault`. This will become obvious when you're looking at the right point in your code.
2. If you don't know what you're supposed to do in the case where you have `Nothing`, but you still want to make a change, then you need a different way of doing so. Instead of pulling the value out of the `Maybe` use `Maybe.map` to change the value while keeping the `Maybe`. As an example, let's say you're doing the following:

   ```
   foo : Maybe Int -> Int
   foo maybeVal =
     let
       innerVal = fromJust maybeVal
     in
       innerVal + 2
   ```

   Instead, you'll want this:

   ```
   foo : Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
   foo maybeVal =
       Maybe.map (\innerVal -> innerVal + 2) maybeVal
   ```

   Notice that the change you wanted is still done in this case, you've simply not handled the case where you have a `Nothing`. You can now pass this value up and down the call chain until you've hit a place where it's natural to use `withDefault` to get rid of the `Maybe`.

What's happened is that we've separated the concerns of "How do I change this value" and "What do I do when it doesn't exist?". We deal with the former using `Maybe.map` and the latter with `Maybe.withDefault`.

## Caveat

There are a small number of cases where you simply **know** that you have a `Just` value and need to eliminate it using `fromJust` as you described, but those cases should be few and far between. There's quite a few that actually have a simpler alternative.

### Example: Attempting to filter a list and get the value out.

Let's say you have a list of `Maybe`s that you want the values of. A common strategy might be:

```
foo : List (Maybe a) -> List a
foo hasAnything =
  let
    onlyHasJustValues = List.filter Maybe.isJust hasAnything
    onlyHasRealValues = List.map fromJust onlyHasJustValues
  in
    onlyHasRealValues
```

Turns out that even in this case, there are clean ways to avoid `fromJust`. Most languages with a collection that has a map and a filter have a method to filter using a `Maybe` built in. Haskell has `Maybe.mapMaybe`, Scala has `flatMap`, and Elm has `List.filterMap`. This transforms your code into:

```
foo : List (Maybe a) -> List a
foo hasAnything =
  let
    onlyHasRealValues = List.filterMap (\x -> x) hasAnything
  in
    onlyHasRealValues
```

Comment: I get the general sentiment, but I explicitly stated my use case: I have an `Array a`, which I know to be non-empty (because it is a constant), and I want to sample a random element, but the functions in Elm's API I found for this give me a `Maybe a` (because they were designed for general `Array a`s, which could be empty and/or have some indexes be out-of-bounds for them). Do you have suggestions for this case? The nonempty list type in a comment is nice, but no longer O(1), and in general I can't expect to be able to encode the impossibility of every similar failure mode in the type system.

Comment: So couple thoughts:
1) You can select a random element from a list which you correctly point out is not O(1)...Unless you know that the size of the list is a small constant, in which case who cares, use the list. List has a better interface in Elm.
2) If this is for a small toy project, then don't worry about it. Use your Debug.crash implementation.
3) If you're doing this for a larger production database, then attempt to implement this as cleanly as possible.

Finally, you can expect to encode impossibility in a lot of cases. I've been bitten by not doing so before.

Comment: If this specific use case were hypothetically for a larger production database, you still haven't given me any concrete details about how to "implement this as cleanly as possible"...