# Array vs List in Elm

Tags: arrays, list, elm

I was suprised to learn that `Array` and `List` were two different types in Elm:

- [`Array`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Array)
- [`List`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/List)

In my case, I have a `List Int` of length 2,000,000 and I need about 10,000 of them but I don't know in advance which ten thousand.  That will be provided by another list.  In pseudo-code:

```
x = [ 1,1,0,30,...,255,0,1 ]
y = [ 1,4,7,18,36,..., 1334823 , ... 1899876 ]
z = [ y[x[0]], y[x[1]], ... ]
```

I am using pseudocode because clearly this isn't Elm syntax (it might be legal JavaScript).

Can these array selections be done in `List` or `Array` or both?

Comment: `List` is a linked-list structure, so the expression `y[x[i]]` is an O(n) lookup for the `i`th in `x` plus another O(n) lookup for the element in `y`. In other words, for 10000 lookups among 2mil elements this will be prohibitively slow. Use Array.

Comment: Unless `y` is guaranteed to be sorted, then a different algorithm will work

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's the broader problem your solving by picking 10.000 elements out of a 2.000.000 element list?

Comment: the 2 million elements are pixels from an image. I am given 10000 points and I need to find their RGB color. I can ask a new question if you like

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`List` is a linked list which provides O(n) lookup time based on index. Getting an element by index requires traversing the list over `n` nodes. An index lookup function for `List` isn't available in the core library but you can use the [elm-community/list-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/2.0.1/List-Extra) package which provides two functions for lookup (varying by parameter order): [`!!`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/2.0.1/List-Extra#!!) and [`getAt`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/2.0.1/List-Extra#getAt).

`Array` allows for *O(log n)* index lookup. Index lookups on `Array` can be done using [`Array.get`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Array#get). Arrays are represented as [Relaxed Radix Balanced Trees](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.12.1#arrays).

Both are immutable (all values in Elm are immutable), so you have trade-offs depending on your situation. `List` is great when you make a lot of changes because you are merely updating linked list pointers, whereas `Array` is great for speedy lookup but has somewhat poorer performance for modifications, which you'll want to consider if you're making a lot of changes.

Comment: I didn't check, but I'd have thought Array was some form of red-black tree with O(lg n) lookup?

Comment: @SørenDebois you are absolutely right, the lookup is O(lg n) in Elm's `Array`

Comment: Looks like Array is using [Relaxed Radix Balanced Trees](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.12.1#arrays) under the hood. I've updated my answer.

Comment: For folding or mapping over, what is better, `Array` or `List`?

Comment: In general terms, `List` will have better performance for folding and mapping because it's "one step" to the next item. `Array`s will be better for indexed lookups but perform slightly worse for folding and mapping because they have a few more steps to get to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import Array
import Debug

fromJust : Maybe a -> a
fromJust x = case x of
    Just y -> y
    Nothing -> Debug.crash "error: fromJust Nothing"

selectFromList : List a -> List Int -> List a
selectFromList els idxs = 
  let arr = Array.fromList els
   in List.map (\i -> fromJust (Array.get i arr)) idxs
```

It converts the input list to an array for fast indexing, then maps the list of indices to their corresponding values in the array. I took the `fromJust` function from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699800/right-way-to-forcibly-convert-maybe-a-to-a-in-elm-failing-clearly-for-nothings).

Answer (score 0):

**Only use `Array` if you need to use [`Array.get`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Array#get).**

In most cases you should use `List` because usually you can do everything you need with `foldl`, `map`, etc. without having to get items from an index, and `List` has better performance with these functions.