# Elm Multiple Counter code using List

Tags: elm

Im new to Elm , previously I was doing `React`, `Redux` , `ES6`
Need help optimizing the below counter example using `Array` rather than `List`.
Getting error Type mismatch When I tried to use `Array Set/Get` methods.

```
import Html exposing (beginnerProgram, div, button, text, p, Html, span)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Array

main =
  beginnerProgram { model = [0,7], view = view, update = update }


view model =
  div []
    [ div [] [ button [ onClick AddCounter ] [ text "Add Counter" ] ]
      , div [] (List.indexedMap  (\index data -> (viewCounter index data)) model)
    ]
viewCounter: Int -> Int -> Html Msg
viewCounter index data =
    div [] [
    p [] [text ("Counter " ++ toString index )]
    , button [ onClick (Decrement index) ] [ text "-" ]
    , span [] [ text (toString data) ]
    , button [ onClick (Increment index) ] [ text "+" ]
    ]


type Msg = 
  AddCounter 
  | Increment Int
  | Decrement Int

incrementSelectedIndex index selectedIndex data = 
  if index == selectedIndex then data + 1
  else data

decrementSelectedIndex index selectedIndex data = 
  if index == selectedIndex then data + 1
  else data


update msg model =
  case msg of
    AddCounter ->
      List.append model [0] 

    Increment selectedIndex ->
      (List.indexedMap  (\index data -> 
        (incrementSelectedIndex index selectedIndex data)) model)  

    Decrement selectedIndex ->
      (List.indexedMap  (\index data -> 
        (decrementSelectedIndex index selectedIndex data)) model)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.get` returns a `Maybe a` since the requested index may not be found. This may be different than other languages with which you have experience, which tend to throw exceptions when an index is out of bounds.

In Elm, the `Maybe` type has two possible values: `Nothing`, and `Just a` where `a` is the actual value you care about.

You can use a `case` statement to differentiate between the two options. Here is an example of what your `Increment` case can look like using Array's `get` and `set` functions:

```elm
Increment selectedIndex ->
  case Array.get selectedIndex model of
    Just val -> Array.set selectedIndex (val + 1) model
    Nothing -> model
```

Notice that if we ask for a nonexistent index, we would get `Nothing` and just return the original array rather than crashing the program.

Comment: Finally I understood Maybe effortlessly , Many Thanks Chad.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to use either Array or List for such use case , please clarify w.r.t to performance (memory & speed). .

Comment: There's a bit more info along with links [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707577/array-vs-list-in-elm)