# How to convert Maybe (List) to Just List in Elm?

Tags: list, elm, option-type

I have a list which is comprised of a list of strings, declared as:

```
type alias Model =
    { board : List (List String)
    }

init : Model
init =
    { board = 
        [ ["", "", ""]
        , ["", "", ""]
        , ["", "", ""]
        ]
    }
```

In my update function, I am attempting to access an inner element of the lists via

```
(getAt col (getAt row model.board))
```

I get the following error when I try to compile it though. How do I convert from Maybe List to Just List or simply List?

```
The 2nd argument to `getAt` is not what I expect:

65|                         (getAt col (getAt row model.board))
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This `getAt` call produces:

    Maybe (List String.String)

But `getAt` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    List a
```

Comment: That's the thing, Elm forces you to handle the case where there's not element and `getAt` returns nothing. You can either use a `case .. of` or `Maybe.withDefault` and there's probably other ways as well but all of them will require you to specify what should happen if there's no element, on way or another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right way to forcibly convert Maybe a to a in Elm, failing clearly for Nothings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699800/right-way-to-forcibly-convert-maybe-a-to-a-in-elm-failing-clearly-for-nothings)

Answer (score 1):

First to answer your question: 
use [`case .. of`](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/pattern_matching.html) or [`Maybe.withDefault`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe#withDefault).

But it looks like you want to do something, for what a list is not the right solution.

If you have a list, and you know it is never empty, use something like a [List.Nonempty](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/elm-nonempty-list/latest/)

If you know the numbers of entries in each list, use something like a [vector](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Chadtech/elm-vector/latest/)

For your 2D Board, I would suggest creating your own (opaque) custom type. Or maybe [this matrix](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Punie/elm-matrix/latest/) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
model.board
|> getAt row
|> Maybe.withDefault []
|> getAt col
```

OR even better

```
model.board
|> getAt row
|> Maybe.andThen (getAt col)
```

(see https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe for more info)

Answer (score 1):

Also you have [`Maybe.Extra.values`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/latest/Maybe-Extra#values) which does exactly what you want